# kubernetes long args, how to break long arguments into separate line in yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes. I have an issue is if my args are so long and it needs to go to the second line, how to correct the format without messup the Kubernetes yaml file

For exapmle:

```sh
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done, while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,"]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you write a shell script, `COPY` it into your Docker image, and make that the image's default `CMD`?  You wouldn't set `command:` or `args:` with that setup, just let Kubernetes run the container's default command.  That would give you something that's easier to format and test.

Answer (score 6):

K8s manifests are compliant with the [YAML standard](https://yaml.org/). So you can do [multiline](https://yaml-multiline.info/) YAML. For example:

```yaml
--- 
args: 
  - -c   array multiline notation
  - |
      while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,
      while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,
      while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,
      while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,
      while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,
      while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done,
command: 
  - /bin/sh
```

✌️

Comment: sorry, I have this issue /bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "done")

Comment: hmm.. you didn't include `  array multiline notation` correct?

Answer (score 4):

Use a YAML multiline string:

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: 
  - "-c"
  - |
    while true; do echo hello; sleep 10; done
    echo "here's a second line!"
    echo "here's some more text" && \
        _c="chocolate chip"; printf "here's a %s cookie" $_c
```

[More on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines#answer-21699210)

Comment: Commas at the end of lines are not needed